# In VSTS, get the hours logged by an individual for each day in the sprint

Tags: tfs, vsts

We moved to VSTS recently, I wonder if there any Widget or a query to get the hours logged by an individual for each day in the sprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop micromanaging and focusing on low value metrics.

[Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

Additional: Attempting to use *how many hours each person worked* as a tool for issue analysis is dysfunctional.  (It is also a metric that can be easily gamed.)  In order to investigate and address any possible issues, the team needs to have a candid discussion during the Sprint Retrospective ([Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/)) or similar [agile principled reflection](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

Comment: I don't prefer micromanagement. But the burndown looks very terrible in this sprint. Wanted to check what exactly happened.

Comment: How do you expect such data to be helpful?  What is your role?

Comment: @varmabsrk Answer above?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default widget or feature in the product and only the CMMI template has enough fidelity data to get something even close to the data you're after.