# How can I track time spent by assignees on each ticket in JIRA?

Tags: jira, metrics, kanban-board

I want to track time spent by each agent on each task on a [JIRA Kanban board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/glossary/kanban-board). If an agent was assigned a task and he assigns it back to me, I want to track the time he spent assigned to the ticket. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I was thinking of using "Work Log" in the ticket, where users can log in their time. But I am not sure how that can help, cause the "Single Level Group By Report" reports only on the tasks that the user is currently assigned and not on the tasks that are completed. I want to avoid having to use an add-on.

Comment: If people are manually filling in fields, you aren't *really* tracking elapsed times for state transitions; you'd be collecting estimates and guesswork. There's nothing wrong with manual processes, but it's unlikely to yield the results you say you want. Now, whether you actually *need* the data is a different question. 

Comment: You could ask yourself why you find that important? What problem are you really trying to solve? In an agile setting I find this a totally uninteresting metric. In any other setting they would find this important, I wouldn't want to work...

Answer (score 3):

### Tracking Workflow Transitions

Tracking ticket assignments between people is generally considered a workflow or state transition. According to [an Atlassian Confluence document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/tracking-the-time-taken-for-each-workflow-transition-126910724.html), there are some recommended ways for tracking workflow transitions.

> #### Tracking the Time Taken for Each Workflow Transition
>
> Below are 3 solutions which may fulfill your time tracking requirements:
>
> - [JIRA Charts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/displaying-search-results-as-a-chart-185729486.html) can report 'Average Time in Status' as a chart
> - The [JIRA Suite Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities/server/overview) has a 'Transitions Summary' tab panel
> - The [Time in Status app](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.obss.plugin.time-in-status) provides automated time tracking for statuses or assignees
>
> You can also visit the Atlassian Marketplace to review hundreds of time tracking apps and integrations to help you track, plan, and optimize with ease.

If none of the recommended approaches work for you, then Atlassian recommends reviewing your options from the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/). You might also want to look at the [cloud](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/1000.1609.0/) or [developer](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis) APIs if you decide to "roll your own."

Comment: Props to Todd for answering this whilst also biting their tongue about asking why...it's a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stop micromanaging and focusing on low value metrics.

[Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

Attempting to use how many hours each person worked as a tool for issue analysis is dysfunctional. (It is also a metric that can be easily gamed.) In order to investigate and address any possible issues, the team needs to have a candid discussion during the Sprint Retrospective ([Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/index.html)) or similar [agile principled](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) reflection.

(From my [answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/23029/in-vsts-get-the-hours-logged-by-an-individual-for-each-day-in-the-sprint/23037#23037)  for the same regarding VSTS.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a new app on the Marketplace, [Clockwork Automated Timesheets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219213/clockwork-automated-timesheets), that makes time tracking automatic. It integrates with Jira's workflow so that the time logged corresponds to how much time an issue was In Progress or had any other active status. If necessary, the timers can always be started or stopped manually. There are also reports available. The one thing you mentioned and the app can't currently do is to reassign the logged time to another user. Hope that helps.